# Make the `say` terminal utility and NSSpeechSynthesizer work with Siri voices

Tags: macos, text-to-speech, macos-catalina, siri, nsspeechsynthesizer

- The [`say` command-line utility](https://ss64.com/osx/say.html) seems to be unaware of Siri voices as of macOS 11 (Big Sur):

  - `say -v '?'` doesn't list Siri voices.
  - Targeting a Siri voice explicitly doesn't work:

    - `say -v NoraSiri hi!` doesn't find the Nora Siri voice (which is the default Siri voice).
    - *Update*: As [ccpizza's answer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76130163/45375), if a Siri voice happens to be the *system* voice (i.e. the *default* voice), `say` *can* use it, *implicitly*, namely *without `-v`*, starting with macOS Ventura ; the answer also has updated-for-Ventura instructions for how to change the system voice interactively.
  - Using a bundle ID (e.g., `com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.custom.siri.nora.premium`)<sup>[1]</sup> doesn't complain about an unknown voice, but speech output fails with `Open speech channel failed: -86`:

    - `say -v com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.custom.siri.nora.premium hi!`
    - Seemingly, any string with prefix `com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.custom` triggers this error.
- Similarly, [`NSSpeechSynthesizer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer) doesn't list Siri voices as available and doesn't support selecting one for speech output.

macOS Big Sur itself *is* capable of using a Siri voice for TTS, as evidenced by the fact that you can select one as the system voice in `System Preferences > Accessibility > Speech`, e.g. in combination with the shortcut-key-based `Speak selected text when the key is pressed` feature.
(Curiously, though, a Siri voice selected as the system voice does *not* take effect if you *right-click* text and select `Speech > Start Speaking` from the context menu and possibly also not for other accessibility features - this discrepancy is the subject of [this MacRumors forum thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/wrong-system-voice-speak-text-and-alerts-catalina.2237933/?post=28619208#post-28619208).)

Unfortunately, it appears that this functionality isn't exposed through a utility or API.

- Is there any way to use Siri voices with `say` or `NSSpeechSynthesizer`?

---

[1] The bundle IDs of the *installed* Siri voices can be determined as follows:

```bash
ls /System/Library/Speech/Voices/*.SpeechVoice/Contents/Info.plist | grep -i siri | xargs -n 1 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'print CFBundleIdentifier'
```

<sup>Note: The above works for me as of macOS Big Sur, upgraded from an earlier version, with at least one Siri voice installed. [Siu Ching Pong -Asuka Kenji-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142239/siu-ching-pong-asuka-kenji) reports that on a freshly installed, non-upgraded Big Sur machine the `System/Library/Speech/Voices` directory is empty.</sup>

To find the bundle IDs of all *available* (downloadable) Siri voices:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'print DownloadableCustomVoices' /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeechObjects.framework/Resources/SpeechDataDefaults.plist | grep 'VoiceIdentifier' | sed -E 's/.+ = //'
```

Comment: I am testing your command for listing bundle IDs. It does not work on my machine (macOS Big Sur Version 11.4). The directory `/System/Library/Speech/Voices/` is empty. It seems that the files are moved to `/System/Library/SpeechBase/Voices/`. However, the files for Siri are not found there (`grep` does not match anything).

Comment: On my machine (macOS Big Sur Version 11.4), the voice identifiers for Siri could be found inside the file `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeechObjects.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SpeechDataDefaults.plist`.

Comment: That is curious, @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji-: For me, the original command still works, as of macOS Big Sur 11.5.1

Comment: Perhaps it is because mine is a clean install of macOS Big Sur. When I installed Big Sur, I wiped out all the things on my Mac. The fact that your command still works on your machine may be due to upgrading from a previous version of macOS. Those files are carried from the old one. By the way, I am curious whether my locations work on your machine too. 

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji-: indeed, my machine is upgraded, but please note that your file - also present in earlier versions - is just a _catalog_ of _metadata_ about _downloadable_ voices, whereas my command lists only the _installed_ Siri voices. I've added a command to extract the bundle IDs of all _downloadable_ Siri voices too. (As an aside: `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeechObjects.framework/Resources/SpeechDataDefaults.plist` is the better path to use (`/Versions/A` removed).

Comment: On my M1 MacBook Pro with Big Sur (never upgraded), the expected system voice are presents in /System/Library/Speech/Voices but "say -v" does not work as noted above. By "expected" I mean those available to me in the Accessibility Sys Pref pane (including AronSiri, Alison, Ava, NoraSiri, Samantha, and Tom).

Comment: Added for completeness: I can get high quality Tom or other on-Siri voices to work in Terminal when they are selected as "System Voice" in Accessibility.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a WWDC20 talk, Apple says Siri voices are not available in AVSpeechSynthesizer.

The talk is called "[Create a seamless speech experience in your apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10022/)." Apparently this applies to Catalina as well.

Here's the relevant slide:

[image: WWDC20 Slide]

I started a [thread at macrumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/wrong-system-voice-speak-text-and-alerts-catalina.2237933/?post=28619208) regarding similar problems configuring the system voice to speak text.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan - that seems to be the answer as of macOS Catalina (10.15). However, it sounds like there is hope this may eventually be implemented in a future version, which would be [macOS Big Sur (11.0)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) at the earliest.

Comment: I wonder whether anyone has experience with Siri voices in macOS Monterey? As of macOS 11.6, Siri voices are still not available.

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the original question, explicitly selecting a siri voice with `say -v <some-siri-voice>` does *not* work, yet what does seem to work (verified on Ventura, 13.0.1) is selecting a Siri voice as the system default under <kbd></kbd> ⇾ <kbd>System settings...</kbd> ⇾ <kbd>Accessibility</kbd> ⇾ <kbd>Spoken Content</kbd> ⇾ <kbd>System voice</kbd> ⇾ <kbd>Manage voices...</kbd> ⇾ [select a downloaded siri voice]  ⇾ click <kbd>Ok</kbd>, and then use e.g. `say nobody expects the spanish inquisition` (*without* `-v`).

> ❗️ This behaviour does not seem to be available on versions prior to Ventura, e.g. on Monterey (12.0.1) and earlier, `say` will *not* use a siri voice if it's set as system default.

Comment: @mklement0: you are right, updated the config steps; the op implied that siri voices do not 'work' with `say` while in practice it does not work when selecting those voices explicitly with `-v name` yet it does work using the _System voice_ workaround, which is of course not perfect.

Comment: @mklement0: checked on a monterey system, and found that `say` won't use a siri voice if it's set as system default and falls back to a lower quality ootb voice; answer updated

Answer (score -7):

Using the keyboard shortcut can activate the new Siri voice (noraSiri)

Comment: Thanks, but that is already mentioned in the question (the paragraph that starts with  "The OS itself ..."). What I'm looking for are _programmatic_ ways of using Siri voices.